# Como evitar sobrecarga de requisições HTTP ao consumir API REST?

Tags: laravel, api, rest, http

Tenho uma API REST feita com Laravel e uma WebApp (que usa os recursos desta API) feita em Angular.JS. Minha WebApp é um portal exclusivo para usuário cadastrados, mas agora estou criando um site para que usuários não cadastrados possam apenas consultar algumas coisas.

Eu resolvi fazer um site normal porque desta forma os buscadores podem indexar mais facilmente o site e isso deve ajudar a melhorar a posição do site nos resultados das buscas no google, por exemplo.

Entretanto agora estou enfrentando um grande problema. Minha ideia era que o site aproveitasse os recursos que a API já fornece (para não precisar fazer novas implementações). Até ai tudo bem, funcionou, mas ficou muuuuito lento devido a sobrecarga de Requisições HTTP. Basicamente quando se clica em um link no site é gerada uma Requisição HTTP e quando o servidor vai buscar o conteúdo na API é gerada outra Requisição HTTP.

No meu ambiente local de desenvolvimento, o simples acesso a uma pagina com uma lista de itens fornecidos pela API já demora 2,5 segundos, me deixando muito preocupado com o desempenho que isso terá em outros cenários. No final das contas esta me parecendo que é bem vantajoso ter um API para WebApps e para Apps mas muito ruim para Sites.

**Minhas perguntas são**: Como resolver esta situação? Este é um preço a pagar por usar uma API? Tem alguma coisa que eu possa fazer para evitar esta sobrecarga de requisições? Algum plugin, pacote ou esquema de rede?

Answer (score 11):

Esta é uma questão mais de arquitetura do que a respeito de REST APIs. Quaisquer aplicaçõees, tecnologias ou plataformas que não levem em consideração possíveis cargas de uso podem se tornar lentas.

Uma das técnicas que aplicações com grande tráfego de dados utilizam é *caching*, ou armazenamento temporário. A idéia é prevenir acessos a recursos que consumam  tempo de processamento ou entrem em estado de espera (como acesso a banco, disco e LDAP, por exemplo).

Alguns níveis de *caching* que você pode implementar:

- **Banco**: Se sua aplicação estiver gastando muito tempo aguardando a resposta de uma *query* ou *stored procedure*, considere o armazenamento de resultados de pesquisa razoavelmente estáticos em tabelas temporárias (também chamadas *staging tables*).
- **DAL (Data Access layer)**: Sempre que possível, implemente um mecanismo que armazene o resultado de consultas feitas ao banco na memória ([MemCached](http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/memcached-for-c----a-walkthrough/62), [Redis](http://redis.io/)) e re-utilize o resultado obtido ao invés de consultar de novo.
- **Cache distribuído**: Caso você tenha vários servidores realizando consultas basicamente estáticas em uma mesma base de dados, utilize um mecanismo de cache distribuído para armazenar seus dados. Isso irá permitir que apenas uma consulta seja feita ao banco.
- **Cache de resultado da operação GET**: Você pode adicionar um *header* à resposta informando que o valor não será alterado por um determinado período de tempo, prevenindo assim novas requisições oriundas da aplicação web.

Você pode também implementar várias destas técnicas em paralelo.